# Complex version of chain rule.

Tags: complex-analysis, chain-rule

I was slightly confused with some of the other posts concerning the complex version of the chain rule.
It is stated as follows in other questions:
$\frac{\partial h}{\partial z} = \frac{\partial g}{\partial z}\frac{\partial f}{\partial z} + \frac{\partial g}{\partial \bar z}\frac{\partial \bar f}{\partial z}$

Where h = $g\circ f$, $g:U \rightarrow \mathbb C$ and $f: V \rightarrow U$

When using the multi-variable version, The "denomiator" of the del g term is del z, whereas shouldn't be del f?

As in:
$\frac{\partial h}{\partial z} = \frac{\partial g}{\partial f}\frac{\partial f}{\partial z} + \frac{\partial g}{\partial \bar f}\frac{\partial \bar f}{\partial z}$

Any insight is appreciated.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Please provide some background.  What is $f$, $g$, and $h$?

Comment: Yes, I am very sorry for the sloppiness. I have edited the post.

Comment: If $\partial$ is used to mean the partial derivative in the usual sense, then $g$ is probably a function of $z, \bar{z}$ and not $f, \bar{f}$, so your form doesn't make sense.  Maybe you're concerned about where we evaluate the partials?  That is legitimate (it might come down to notation), but it can't be fixed that way.